# NGRX effects and order of actions

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

My goal is to handle two parallel actions in effect.

action1 is generating once. action2 is generating several times but I need only last value at the time when action1 generated.
The problem that I faced if action2 generated first and then action1 we will see in console 'action3' as expected. But, if action1 generated first and then action2 we will not see in console 'action3'

```
  testEffect$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(action1),
        tap((act) => window.console.log('action1')),
        withLatestFrom(
          this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(action2),
            tap((act) => window.console.log('action2'))
          )
        ),
        tap((act) => window.console.log('action3')),
        mapTo(action3)
      ),
    { dispatch: false }
  );

  constructor(private readonly actions$: Actions) {}
```

I expected to see 'action3' in both cases but seems withLatestFrom filters action1 if action2 generated after.

Why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### About `withLatestFrom`

For `withLatestFrom`, all input Observables must emit at least one value before the output Observable will emit a value.

Also:

> **Whenever the source Observable emits a value**, it computes a formula using that value plus the latest values from other input Observables, then emits the output of that formula.

The effect is that if the source emits a value, and there is no latest values from other input Observables -> nothing happens. It just waits for the source to emit again.

---

#### A possible solution:

Give your other input observable a default value to fall back on if it hasn't emitted a value yet. This can be done in many ways, but `startWith` is fairly straight-forward and works well if the default value doesn't need to change.

```
withLatestFrom(
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(action2),
    startWith(null),
    tap(_ => console.log('action2'))
  )
),
```

Of course, null isn't a great default value for action2. You can use something more semantically meaningful if that helps your logic later on.

---

#### An Aside:

On the other hand `MapTo(action3)` negates the work you're doing anyway, so I'm really not sure why you have the requirements that you do.

You're combining two observables and then ignoring the output. Why not just do:

```
this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(action1),
   mapTo(action3)
)
```

That should have the semantics you described.